# Android Share Intent using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, share

I really have no idea how to implement Share Intent into my codes. Could somebody assist me, Do i need to rewrite the whole code code? I'm using AsyncTask for my share intent. I would like to share my image using the share intent. Please check my below code, something is missing for "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type ShareImageTask" .

ShareImageTask.class

```
    public class ShareImageTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>
{
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String image_url;
    URL myFileUrl;
    String myFileUrl1;
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    Intent share;


    public ShareImageTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Image ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {  

            myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();   
            conn.setDoInput(true);   
            conn.connect();     
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {       
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
        try {       

            String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
            String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Wallpaper/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = idStr;
            File file = new File(dir, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);   
            fos.flush();    
            fos.close();     
            share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");

            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,file);

            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image")); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }




        return null;   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pDialog.dismiss();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

So you point to your Activity's Context in your AsyncTask, and not to the AsyncTask itself. Right now you're calling a method `AsyncTask::startActivity()`, but that doesn't exist. Because you're in the inner class, you gotta have the object you want to call `startActivity()` on. That's the `context` variable you set.

Comment: yeah its working. But I have another problem, my share intent doesn't capture anything. Do you want me to open another question?

Answer (score 1):

You should call startActivity(Intent) from your Activity instance in onPostExecute(which will be run on UI thread), e.g.

```
class MyActivity {
  public class ShareImageTask extends AsyncTask<String , String , String> {
      . . .
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        . . . 
        return file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
        share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, file[0]);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image")); //<<--The 

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android Developers Blog has an article on sharing content using intents: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html